# Can't the Password File In Oracle 12.2 C

Tags: oracle-12c

I intend to to make password file, spfile and control files as part of my backup script, but i however i have been trying to get find the password file in the $ORACLE_HOME/dbs location but its not there. Where do i find it.

Comment: do you use ASM, Oracle Restart, Oracle RAC?

Answer (score 0):

> I intend to to make password file, spfile and control files as part of my backup script

Let RMAN take care of both the [SPFILE and Control Files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/backup.102/b14192/bkup003.htm#i1006341):

```
CONFIGURE CONTROLFILE AUTOBACKUP ON
```

The Password File should be swept up by your Server backup.